# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am writing a Java Spring MVC application. When I checked the url (http://localhost:8080/ui/processes), it didn't render the view but throw exceptions like this:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.getClassLoader(ContextHandler.java:2390)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagPluginManager.init(TagPluginManager.java:73)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagPluginManager.apply(TagPluginManager.java:57)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:241)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
```

My web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>static</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>static</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

the static-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.service.mypackage" />

<bean class = 
"org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name = "prefix" value = "/jsp/" />
    <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
</bean>
```

the Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/processes")
public class ProcessesController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView printProcesses(){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("Processes");
    model.addObject("msg", "hello process");
    return model;
}
}
```

the Process.jsp is a simple html file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Process </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> HAHAHAHA!!!! </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I am very new to the Spring MVC and all steps followed tutorials. Anyone knows what caused the exception above and how to resolve it?

Comment: Your web.xml is wrong. Your can refer to [this tutorial](https://crunchify.com/servlet-tutorial-getting-starting-with-jsp-servlet-example/) for detail to fix it

Comment: The DispatcherSerbvlet will handle the controller mapping (it works in my application, I put some System.out.print in the controller to verify if the dispatcher find the correct one). And the controller no longer need to extends HttpServlet and implement doGet and doPost methods.